Spark executoras are not spawn on Kubernetes worker node
I have a kubernetes cluster and I am running a spark connect server on the cluster using the client mode. The problem is that the spark worker nodes are not spawned on the Kubernetes worker node and all of them are spanning on the master node:
I am using below command to run spark on Kubernetes, running around 10 executors each having 4G ram on a master node of 32g. The cluster should spawn some of the worker nodes on the worker node but some spark worker nodes remain pending and not being spawned on the worker. All cluster nodes status are ready.
./spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0 --deploy-mode client --master k8s://https://10.96.0.1:443 --conf spark.executor.instances=10 --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=0.0.0.0 --conf spark.driver.host=172.22.0.80 --conf spark.driver.port=29413 --conf spark.blockManager.port=7078 --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=default --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark-py:latest --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName=spark --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=2  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=2 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.sidecar.istio.io/inject=false --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.annotation.sidecar.istio.io/inject=false --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/root/kspark --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp"  --conf spark.executor.memory=4G --conf spark.driver.memory=4G

see below:
root@master-node:~# kubectl get pods -n default -o wide
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-1    1/1     Running   0          5m41s   10.0.1.21    master-node   <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-10   0/1     Pending   0          5m39s   <none>       <none>        <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-2    1/1     Running   0          5m41s   10.0.1.25    master-node   <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-3    1/1     Running   0          5m41s   10.0.1.48    master-node   <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-4    1/1     Running   0          5m40s   10.0.1.67    master-node   <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-5    1/1     Running   0          5m40s   10.0.1.49    master-node   <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-6    1/1     Running   0          5m39s   10.0.1.213   master-node   <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-7    0/1     Pending   0          5m39s   <none>       <none>        <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-8    0/1     Pending   0          5m39s   <none>       <none>        <none>           <none>
spark-connect-server-db40ad938cd78997-exec-9    0/1     Pending   0          5m39s   <none>       <none>        <none>           <none>

The cluster status is ready:
root@master-node:~# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME          STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION                       CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master-node   Ready    control-plane   2d2h   v1.31.3   172.22.0.80      <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS   5.15.0-125-generic                   docker://24.0.7        
worker-node   Ready    <none>          9h     v1.31.3   172.21.133.245   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS   5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.7.12 

Can anyone give me any clue, howe to fix this?
